# Parsing XML to read in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I am trying to put the contents of an XML file into an `NSMutableArray`.  I want to be able to get the following result:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [myarray objectAtIndex: 1];  will return cookie.
```

The xml file looks like this:

```
<row>
<Word>aardvark</Word>
</row>

<row>
<Word>cookie</Word>
</row>
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
-(void)checkdictionary {
    NSString *xmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"englishwords" ofType:@"xml"];
    NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:xmlPath];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser parse];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
    qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Word"]){

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some delegate methods to implement when using [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsxmlparser_class/reference/reference.html) class.

If your purpose is to get all the word contained between the `Word` XML tag, you can do this way.

In your .h file create a BOOL named _isWordTag and a NSMutableArray names _words.

```
@interface MyClass
{
    BOOL _isWordTag;
    NSMutableArray _words;
}
```

Then, in the .m file set the BOOL named _isWordTag and the NSMutableArray named _words.

```
- (id)init
{
    ...
    _isWordTag = NO;
    _words = [NSMutableArray array];
    ...
}
```

To use NSXMLParer you have to implement some delegate from [NSXMLParserDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Word"])
    {
        _isWordTag = YES;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Word"])
    {
        _isWordTag = NO;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{    
    if (_isWordTag)
    {
        [_words addObject:string];
    }
}
```